# Overload Generics in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

I newb in typescript. The issue is I want promisify `verify` method from "jsonwebtoken", but cannot get typing right

```
const verify = util.promisify<string, string | Buffer, {id: string}>(jwt.verify); // First attempt

const verify = util.promisify<string, string | Buffer, jwt.VerifyOptions | undefined, {id: string}>(jwt.verify); // Second attempt

... 

const {id} = await verify(token, SECRET) // Want to use like here
```

The first attempt one gives the error `No overload matches the call`.

Second attempt I need to provide third parameter for promisified `verify`.

```
const {id} = await verify(token, SECRET, undefined) // works with second attempt, but 3 argument is undefined
```

Please help to define correctly `util.promisify` generic types.

Comment: Does this code constitute a [mcve]?  Ideally someone could drop it into any IDE with no external dependencies (unless they are tagged here... is "jsonwebtoken" a dependency?  tag it) and the only errors would be the ones you are asking about.  Right now I don't have enough information to make a suggestion.  Good luck!

Comment: Yeah you can. Just need to support typescript.